# Functions of several variables composition

Tags: functions, function-construction, vector-calculus

If we have two functions $G,F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ then the mechanism
$F\circ G(x,y)=F(G(x,y))$ gives us a new map $F\circ G:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ called its composition.

In a "schematic" view, and with two functions for an example,
we would write
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)
\stackrel{G}\to
\left(\begin{array}{c}x^2y\\2y\end{array}\right)\qquad {\rm and}\qquad
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)
\stackrel{F}\to
\left(\begin{array}{c}x-y\\x\end{array}\right)
$$
then
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)
\stackrel{F\circ G}\longrightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{c}x^2y-2y\\x^2y\end{array}\right).
$$

How could this process be programmed in Mathematica12?

Comment: Maybe you want `@*` ?

Comment: ^ the above is shorthand for [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html). There is also [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) if you want to build up the composition in order of how the functions are applied, e.g `(f /* g /* h)[x]`  gives `h[g[f[x]]]`